# Подключение к компьютеру в локальной сети и открытие сетевой папки

Tags: java

Можно ли с помощью Java подключиться к компьютеру в локальной сети (логин и пароль тоже нужно ввести) и открыть сетевую папку (как на картинке) для работы с ее файлами?

[image: сетевая_папка]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Протокол сетевого взаимодействия, результаты которого как бэ нарисованы на картинке - называется [CIFS: Common Internet File System](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc939973.aspx)

Есть Java библиотека, которая полностью реализует весь указанный протокол. Речь идет о [Java CIFS Client Library](https://jcifs.samba.org)

Берете либу, подключаете к своему проекту - дальше enjoy